# how to make my app as default launcher when press home, as an OPTIONAL feature

Tags: android, android-homebutton

i want to know if i can set my app as default launcher when i want it to be (not a fixed feature) , because i'm developing babies game ,and i want to put lock buttons as an option so i can handle home button when pressed. and when the app is finished return the original launcher.
i searched about it in the internet but all i found is to set it as fixed feature in `manifest` file like this:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

So any help

thanx

Answer (score 0):

> i want to know if i can set my app as default launcher when i want it to be

No, you cannot. The *user* can elect to make your app be their default home screen. Malware authors cannot attack users by forcibly replacing their home screen with another implementation.

Comment: thank you, and sorry for mess understand , i mean i want the user to select it to be the default home screen , but i want to make this feature is optional (can be enabled & disabled)

Comment: @KhalilTam: You can use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to enable and disable your activity that has the `MAIN`/`HOME` `<intent-filter>`. When it is enabled, the user will get a chooser when they next press the HOME button, and they can elect to choose to use your home screen.

Comment: the activity that has <intent-filter> is my main activity ,so how can i disable it ? because i tried but the app was crashed

Comment: @KhalilTam: You could try moving the `<intent-filter>` for `HOME` off of that activity and onto an `<activity-alias>` that points to the activity. Then, in theory, you could enable and disable the alias. I do not recall having tried this, though.

Comment: i was trying something similar , by making new activity to handle <HOME> , the main activity , and starting activity (for loading stuff) (which it's extend from main) and it's the default launch activity of my app. and for Now everything is OK! and it's worked , thank you